# /bin/mv: cannot stat ‘/opt/cisco-amp/download?product=LinuxProduct’: No such file or directory

Tags: shell-script, mv

/bin/mv: cannot stat ‘/opt/cisco-amp/download?product=LinuxProduct’: No such file or directory,  I am getting this error while call this cmd in my shell script "/bin/mv "/opt/cisco-amp/download?product=LinuxProduct" "/opt/cisco-amp/amp_Server_rhel-centos-7.rpm"

Comment: well, do you have a file called that?

Comment: First of all, when I call wget why it's downloading as a weird name but When I call the browser it's downloading as an rpm file.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and start from the beginning: tell us what system you are using, what you are trying to do, what you expect to happen and what actually happens. You haven't even shown us what command you are running here, so we really cannot help. How does wget come into this? Please take a step back and explain what is going on from the beginning.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.